# use pure js variable in vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I' using laravel with vue. In assets folder I created bra.js file with variable.

```
var name="John"
```

Then in main.js I added bra.js

```
require('./bra');
```

I want to use var name in component.vue like below but I can't.

```
 <template>
 <div>
 <p> {{ name }}</p>
 </div>
 </template>
```

Please help.

Comment: you could try global variable window.name = "John", something like that, and  use the same in vue component

Comment: require is a `common` module, you have to export a variable, then import `const bra = require('./bra')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Variable visibility in the template:

```vue
<template>
  <span>{{ variableVisibleInTemplate }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      variableVisibleInTemplate: variableVisibleInScript
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

## Example 1:

You return exactly one variable

**src/assets/bra.js**

```js
var name = "John";

module.exports = name;
```

**src/App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <span>{{ name }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import name from "./assets/bra.js";
// or:
// const name = require("./assets/bra.js");

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: name
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

## Example 2

You return many variables

**src/assets/bra.js**

```js
var name = "John";

module.exports = {
  name: name
};
```

**src/App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <span>{{ name }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import { name } from "./assets/bra.js";
// or:
// const { name } = require("./assets/bra.js");

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: name
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Read also: [Understanding module.exports and exports in Node.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)/[export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) directives.

**src/assets/bra.js**

```
export const name = "John";
```

**src/component.vue**

```
<script>
import { name } from "@/assets/bra";

export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      name: name
    }
  }
  ...
};
</script>
```